# Using setTimeout in react-native-reanimated 2.3.0

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated-v2

Is it possible to somehow call setTimeout on UI Thread in react-native-reanimated 2? Or better yet, use lodash's throttle?

Right now calling setTimeout results in **Tried to synchronously call function {setTimeout} from a different thread.**

Below is a simplified code of what I'm trying to achieve.

```js
const handleSliderDrag = useAnimatedGestureHandler<PanGestureHandlerGestureEvent, { startX: number }>({
    onStart: (_, ctx) => {
        ctx.startX = x.value;
    },

    onActive: (event, ctx) => {
        x.value = ctx.startX + event.translationX;

        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log('hello from timeout');
        }, 200);
    },
});
```

I need to update the redux state on slider drag, but the call from UI to JS is async, and given many events, the calls stack up quickly.

#### Edit 1

I've used Date.now as a workaround, so far works ok, not sure how it could backfire.

```js
const handleSliderDrag = useAnimatedGestureHandler<PanGestureHandlerGestureEvent, { startX: number; now: number }>({
    onStart: (_, ctx) => {
        ctx.startX = x.value;
        ctx.now = Date.now();
    },

    onActive: (event, ctx) => {
        x.value = ctx.startX + event.translationX;
        const now = Date.now();

        if (now - ctx.now > 150) {
            ctx.now = now;
            runOnJS(setCurrent)(x.value);
        }
    },

    onEnd: (event, ctx) => {
        x.value = ctx.startX + event.translationX;
        runOnJS(setCurrent)(x.value);
    },
});
```

Comment: useDebounce might be an good approach https://github.com/xnimorz/use-debounce

Comment: this library uses setTimeout under the hood, so no luck

Comment: useDebounce Will prevent multiple calls

Comment: Were you able to find a solution. I think that would fix this situation - https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-reanimated/discussions/2643 - where we want to schedule things for "next frame".